# Domain Url showing Twice in laravel 10 app

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-10

i have created a project in laravel 10 using breeze. i am facing problem with url. the domain name is showing twice.

ALIAS :

```
Alias /bcl "D:/projects/bcl/public/"

<Directory "D:/projects/bcl/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require all granted
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
</Directory>
```

In .env
APP_URL=http://localhost/
but there is an issue where adding the URL "http://localhost/bcl" is automatically changing to "http://localhost/bcl/bcl".

i tried changing .env file
APP_URL=http://localhost/bcl but still not working. I found a solution here the link is https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/root-directory-is-displayed-twice-in-url-on-load-and-reload?page=1&replyId=791970

but it is suggesting to change vendor files which is not recommended.